# Categorical variable to bin integer data in r

Tags: r

I'd like to create a categorical variable that assigns each value to a bin. So for data like:

```
x   <- floor(runif(50,0,40))
```

The categories will be:

```
g1 <- (x >= 0) & (x<= 10)
g2 <- (x >= 11) & (x<= 20)
g3 <- (x >= 21) & (x<= 30)
g4 <- (x>= 31)
```

The variable should then check x for the categories and assign each observation to a bin. Is there a way to do this in a single variable? Apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't find anything on this specific case.

Comment: You can use the `cut` function.

Comment: `cut(x, breaks = c(0,10,20,30,Inf), labels = c("g1","g2","g3","g4"), include.lowest = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
set.seed(42)
x <- floor(runif(50,0,40))
head(x)
# [1] 36 37 11 33 25 20

head(cut(x, c(0, 10, 20, 30, Inf), include.lowest = TRUE))
# [1] (30,Inf] (30,Inf] (10,20]  (30,Inf] (20,30]  (10,20] 
# Levels: [0,10] (10,20] (20,30] (30,Inf]

head(cut(x, c(0, 10, 20, 30, Inf), labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE))
# [1] 4 4 2 4 3 2
```

The default is to give you `factor`s (first example), which is generally fine for most. The second is if you need an `integer` instead ... it has the same effect, though, in that all numbers that are between (say) 0 and 10 have the same value out of `cut` (a `1` in this case).

In your case, I think you want the `"g1"` labels, so instead of `labels=FALSE`, specify the labels manually (as @Ben just suggested):

```r
head(cut(x, c(0, 10, 20, 30, Inf), labels = paste0("g", 1:4), include.lowest = TRUE))
# [1] g4 g4 g2 g4 g3 g2
# Levels: g1 g2 g3 g4
```

These are also `factor` (you can use `as.character` if you prefer).